# Segmentation fault when removing iterator in stl set

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, segmentation-fault, set

I have a program that iterates through a set and replaces an element, calling itself until it can go no further, then undoes what it did and searches the next branch.

```
for(set<int>::iterator it=set1.begin();it!=set1.end();)
    {
        if(condition)
        {
            int l=*it;
            if(condition) set1.insert(l-rails[inuse]).first;
            set<int>::iterator it1=it;
            it++;
            set1.erase(it1);//this line has the problem
            //do other things, including a recursive call

            if(l>rails[inuse+1]+rails[inuse]) set1.erase(l-rails[inuse]);
            set1.insert(l);
        }
        else ++it;
    }
```

My program appears to run fine, and it works properly on *my* system, but it crashes with a segmentation fault on another system. `valgrind` detects a segmentation violation:

```
==3610== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==3610==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x18
==3610==    at 0x4EA8039: std::_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
==3610==    by 0x402018: std::_Rb_tree<int, int, std::_Identity<int>, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> >::_M_erase_aux(std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>) (stl_tree.h:1497)
==3610==    by 0x401A4A: std::_Rb_tree<int, int, std::_Identity<int>, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> >::erase(std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>) (stl_tree.h:787)
==3610==    by 0x401586: std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> >::erase(std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>) (stl_set.h:517)
==3610==    by 0x40104A: test() (fence8.cpp:32)
==3610==    by 0x40105E: test() (fence8.cpp:34)
==3610==    by 0x40105E: test() (fence8.cpp:34)
==3610==    by 0x40105E: test() (fence8.cpp:34)
==3610==    by 0x40105E: test() (fence8.cpp:34)
==3610==    by 0x40105E: test() (fence8.cpp:34)
==3610==    by 0x40105E: test() (fence8.cpp:34)
==3610==    by 0x40105E: test() (fence8.cpp:34)
```

but I can't understand what's causing this. I assume it has something to do with how I use the iterators, but I can't find it. What might be going wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with all this? At least at first glance, it's not at all clear what you're doing, or why you're doing it as you are. You've explained what you're trying to do in terms of the tree (more or less) itself, but not what all of this is supposed to accomplish.

Comment: What is the purpose of `iterator n`?

Comment: It is no longer used.

Comment: The recursive call is worrying. What if it invalidates `it`?

Comment: Show the entire function, please.  It looks like some evil recursion practice is happening.

Comment: You're making recursive calls to a function that modifies a `std::set` and loops over the entirety of the set from `set1.begin()`?  How can you be sure that a recursive call doesn't modify something earlier to, or (worse) exactly the same as, where you are in the current loop?  If the loop did not start with `set1.begin()` that would not be as difficult to ensure, but it sure does look suspicious to have recursive calls that *could* encounter your "danger iterator" and delete what `it` references!

Comment: @wilsonmichaelpatrick I bet that is the problem. Is there some data structure that can maintain sorted order easily, but at the same time a reference to an element can be kept by value, not index, even if the element with the value is deleted and another is inserted?

Comment: @Jake223 if an element is deleted, then it's no longer in the data structure, so an iterator *into* that data structure for that element doesn't make sense.  I think you need to reconsider your algorithm - recursion is your enemy here, because you'll be changing the data structure *while* you're iterating, then continuing to iterate, which is troublesome to get correct.  In fact some libraries (Cocoa) throw exceptions for such things.

Answer (score 1):

Beware of changing your set while you're iterating - if one of the recursive calls deletes the the element that the iterator `it` is referencing, then it would no longer be valid.  That's a possibility considering each recursive call iterates over the entirety of the set from the beginning.

Comment: If you can build your project with a relatively recent version of MSVC, the debug build has iterator debugging that is really quite good at telling you when you're using an invalidated iterator.